# SharePoint people picker issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, people-picker

We have a web  application which has multiple site collection. We are trying to grant permission to user on site collection but the user doesn't show up in people picker. This problems happens in one site collection how ever we see same user in appearing in other collection by using people picker. Is there any configuration issue why doesn't show up on specific site collection?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run a user profile synchronization service sync. The problem is that the user information list is not sync'd throughout all the web applications. Also, make sure the user profile service application is in the service association that the web application uses.

Comment: Hi Mike, How do I check 2nd point i.e., user profile service application is in the service associate that the web application uses?

Comment: Go to web applications -> Service Associations. Make sure that user profile service is in the group, and not missing. These service associations allows you to have different service applications for different web applications. Most users don't leverage this feature, as it's more for bigger farms.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the hidden User Information List in SharePoint (located at `http://<SiteCollectionUrl>/_catalogs/users/detail.aspx`) and the user isn't in the list, then s/he won't show up in people picker. Like @Mike said, you'll need to run the User Profile Synchronization Service in Central Admin or through PowerShell to sync everything up.

In short, this syncing is a two-step process:

1. A job is run between Active Directory and the User Profile Service Application (the job is called something like `User Profile Service Application - System Job to Manage User Profile Synchronization`. This syncs Active Directory and the UPS Application.
2. A job is run between the User Profile Service Application and SharePoint (the job is called something like `UPS - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization` or `UPS - User Profile to SharePoint Quick Synchronization` -- the full sync for us runs nightly, and the quick sync runs every minute). This syncs the UPS Application with hidden user list in SharePoint.

More info about syncing is at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee721049.aspx and also at https://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/sharepoint-user-information-list-is-not-being-updated/